# How can I implement a 1-time feature on an app?

Tags: android, warnings, prompt

I want to put a prompt into an app about requirements for it and such, but I only want this to show up the first time the app is opened. The only reason why I know it is possible is because I have seen it in other apps. I have no idea where to begin implementing it.

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: Not knowing anything about android per se, but you surely can store some content locally on the device. Then there you have it: Show the feature, save on the device in some file or whatever that you have shown it and check that file/whatever when you open the app to decide if you show the prompt or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Using that, you can do inside the activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences();
if (prefs.getBoolean("is_one_time_action_done", false)) {
  SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
  ed.putBoolean("is_one_time_action_done", true);
  ed.commit();

  // Do your one time action here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). if there is one, then you have already shown the requirements. Else, show the [dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) and save the preference.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the shared preferences to store a boolean flag.